# Is there a way to define a float array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, physics, astronomy

For my astronomy homework, I need to simulate the elliptical orbit of a planet around a sun. To do this, I need to use a for loop to repeatedly calculate the motion of the planet. However, every time I try to run the program, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
r=(x**2+y**2)**1.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "planetenstelsel3-4.py", line 25, in <module>
ax[i] = a(x[i],y[i])*x[i]
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

I've done some testing, and I think the problem lies in the fact that the values that are calculated are greater than what fits in an integer, and the arrays are defined as int arrays. So if there was a way do define them as float arrays, maybe it would work. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dt = 3600 #s
N = 5000
x = np.tile(0, N)
y = np.tile(0, N)
x[0] = 1.496e11 #m
y[0] = 0.0
vx = np.tile(0, N)
vy = np.tile(0, N)
vx[0] = 0.0
vy[0] = 28000 #m/s
ax = np.tile(0, N)
ay = np.tile(0, N)
m1 = 1.988e30 #kg
G = 6.67e-11 #Nm^2kg^-2

def a(x,y):
    r=(x**2+y**2)**1.5
    return (-G*m1)/r

for i in range (0,N):
    r = x[i],y[i]
    ax[i] = a(x[i],y[i])*x[i]
    ay[i] = a(x[i],y[i])*y[i]
    vx[i+1] = vx[i] + ax[i]*dt
    vy[i+1] = vy[i] + ay[i]*dt
    x[i+1] = x[i] + vx[i]*dt 
    y[i+1] = y[i] + vy[i]*dt    
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The first few lines are just some starting parameters.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: ints in python are only limited by your memory

Comment: constants with a `.` are float

Comment: lose your fortran thinking to code in python

Comment: Well, from looking at your code, I don't see why, but for some reason your `a(x,y)` function is receiving a value of `nan` for either x or y.

Comment: And yes, you probably should define your arrays as floats.  If you're using tile, it's as simple as specifying `0.` instead of `0` as the repeated value:  `x = np.tile(0., N)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are doing physics simulations you should definitely use floats for *everything*. `0` is an integer constant in Python, and thus `np.tile` creates integer arrays; use `0.0` as the argument to `np.tile` to do floating point arrays; or preferably use the `np.zeros(N)` instead:

You can check the datatype of any array variable from its `dtype` member:

```
>>> np.tile(0, 10).dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> np.tile(0.0, 10).dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> np.zeros(10)
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> np.zeros(10).dtype
dtype('float64')
```

To get a zeroed array of `float32` you'd need to give a `float32` as the argument:

```
>>> np.tile(np.float32(0), 10)
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

or, preferably, use `zeros` with a defined `dtype`:

```
>>> np.zeros(10, dtype='float32')
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: how to create it with float32??

Comment: @Zibri answered

Comment: You may run into problems if you do not have numpy, nor pip:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_getting_started.asp
Alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

You need `x = np.zeros(N)`, etc.: this declares the arrays as float arrays.

This is the standard way of putting zeros in an array (`np.tile()` is convenient for creating a tiling with a fixed array).